# Loading array of display objects using shared objects in action script 3.0

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, shared-objects, displayobject, adobe-flash-cs3

I'm trying to load an array that contain some display objects, the program lets me to populate the array with circles and save them to a shared object, then, I can trace the content of my array using the load button. The problem is that i can't load the array after that I restart my program. It traces me this message:"objects loaded: ,,,"

This is the code:

```
var SO:SharedObject=SharedObject.getLocal("myFile", "/");

var arr:Array=new Array();

var counter:Number=-1;

addBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addObjects);

saveBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, saveObjects);

loadBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadObjects);

function addObjects(event:Event) {

    counter++;

    var circle:circleClip=new circleClip();

    arr.push(circle);

    trace("current object: "+arr[counter]);
}

function saveObjects(event:Event) {

    SO.data.arrSaved=arr;

    SO.flush();

    trace("objects saved: "+SO.data.arrSaved);
}

function loadObjects(event:Event) {

    var arrLoaded:Array=new Array();

    arrLoaded=SO.data.arrSaved;

    trace("objects loaded: "+arrLoaded);
}
```

Comment: 1. Fix your code. 2. You cannot store **DisplayObject**s as items of **SharedObject**, you can store only plain data types: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#data

Comment: Hi Organis, I'm trying to find a solution but it seems very complicated, I hope there is another solving

Comment: Take a step back. What is that you are trying to achieve by storing display objects?

Comment: I asked more specifically about this web site: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/140488

Comment: if you need i can give you the flash file

Comment: Separate data from visuals and store data only. I posted a guideline below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are to understand MVC pattern approach: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

You need to separate data from the code that visualizes things out of these data, and store data only. Something like:

```
// Lets say this Array contains a list of your circle objects.
var Curcus:Array;

// Storage.
var SO:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("myFile", "/");

function saveCircus():void
{
    var aList:Array = new Array;

    aList.length = Circus.length;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < Curcus.length; i++)
    {
        // Get an object.
        var aCircle:Sprite = Curcus[i];

        // Record its properties you want to store.
        var anEntry:Object =
        {
            "x":aCircle.x,
            "y":aCircle.y,
            "scaleX":aCircle.scaleX,
            "scaleY":aCircle.scaleY
        };

        // Store the entry.
        aList[i] = anEntry;
    }

    // Store and save data.
    SO.data.arrSaved = aList;
    SO.flush();
}

function loadCircus():void
{
    // Retrieve saved data.
    var aList:Array = SO.data.arrSaved;

    // Make it empty data if there are none.
    if (!aList) aList = new Array;

    Circus = new Array;
    Curcus.length = aList.length;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < aList.length; i++)
    {
        // Get one entry.
        var anEntry:Object = aList[i];

        // Create a new item. BTW, naming classes with the
        // lowercase first letter is the 8th cardinal sin.
        var aCircle = new CircleClip;

        // Restore saved properties.
        aCircle.x = anEntry['x'];
        aCircle.y = anEntry['y'];
        aCircle.scaleX = anEntry['scaleX'];
        aCircle.scaleY = anEntry['scaleY'];

        // Add to display list.
        addChild(aCircle);

        // Keep it for the future reference/saving.
        Curcus[i] = aCircle;
    }
}
```