# Saving object state in flash application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, dynamic

i want to write an online application with adobe flash CS6 and Actionscript-3, which is like an online puzzle, but i need to save position of every moving object, for example user moves an object to a new position and i want to save that object state and next time that user loads the page, this object will stay at last state that user placed into
I've tried everything in my mind and still no clue!
thanks

Comment: **SharedObject** is the simplest way to load/save data to/from the local storage in AS3 application. The similar question I posted an answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43690170/4687633

Comment: another solution in addition to above comment, is to providing a password generation (like old games) which save anything as a short text query and a parser for translating passwords to usable data's

Comment: Look at this question and it's answers: 
 http://stackoverflow.com/a/30131304/1457439